# Geoserver does not return JSON when creating a feature

Tags: geoserver, wfs, json

I'm trying to convince Geoserver that it returns JSON after creating a feature in WFS:

POST http://localhost/ows?outputFormat=application/json&exceptions=application/json

BODY:

```
<wfs:Transaction xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs" service="WFS" version="1.1.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wfs http://schemas.opengis.net/wfs/1.1.0/wfs.xsd">
    <wfs:Insert>
        <feature:GEOIP_NETWORKS xmlns:feature="http://edit.tmb.cat">
            <feature:GEOMETRY>
                <gml:Point xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" srsName="EPSG:4326">
                <gml:pos>2.167296 41.381919</gml:pos></gml:Point>
            </feature:GEOMETRY>
            <feature:NETWORK>AAA</feature:NETWORK>
            <feature:DESC_NETWORK>asdasd</feature:DESC_NETWORK>
       </feature:GEOIP_NETWORKS>
    </wfs:Insert>
</wfs:Transaction>
```

However it seems to ignore outputFormat parameter and keeps returning XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wfs:TransactionResponse xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="1.1.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wfs http://tmbapi.tmb.cat:80/geoserver/schemas/wfs/1.1.0/wfs.xsd">
    <wfs:TransactionSummary>
        <wfs:totalInserted>1</wfs:totalInserted>
        <wfs:totalUpdated>0</wfs:totalUpdated>
        <wfs:totalDeleted>0</wfs:totalDeleted>
    </wfs:TransactionSummary>
    <wfs:TransactionResults/>
    <wfs:InsertResults>
        <wfs:Feature>
            <ogc:FeatureId fid="GEOIP_NETWORKS.19"/>
        </wfs:Feature>
    </wfs:InsertResults>
</wfs:TransactionResponse>
```

The exceptions work fine though, does return JSON.

Is it just not implemented yet?

I'm using Geoserver 2.11.1.

Comment: XML is the native language of WFS. As far as I know in version 1.1.1 the outputformat parameter affects only GetFeature.

Comment: Yeah I know, however the docs does not distinguish clearly where is outputFormat accepted and where not.   http://docs.geoserver.org/2.11.1/user/services/wfs/outputformats.html

Comment: as that link contains shapefiles and gml it looks pretty obvious that it is about features

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A WFS service will always expect (and require) requests and responses to be in XML. There is no alternative provided by the specification as interoperability between systems and client languages was a requirement there was no need to support niche formats like JSON.